# Number does not change to next number

Tags: php

I have a string number as below. When i add 1 to it, it changes to a scientific representation instead of a real number and also doesnot increment to the next number. Any reason why its not incrementing?

I want 4600004722057511 to become 4600004722057512

Thanks

Number is 4600004722057501
After adding 1 to it it becomes 4.6000047220575E+15

```
$val = $list[0]->getNextNumber();
$list[0]->setNextNumber($val+1);
```

Comment: Looks like `$val` is a floating point number. Your question/code indicates that you expect it to be an integer.

Comment: I just want it to become 4600004722057512 from 4600004722057511

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, you might be hitting numeric range limits for integers of your PHP implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bcmath for high numbers

```
$val = $list[0]->getNextNumber();
$val = bcadd( $val, 1 ); // here you add 1 to a very high number
$list[0]->setNextNumber($val);
```

Comment: @user3855851 take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with add “(int)” your code

```php
$val = (int)$list[0]->getNextNumber();
$list[0]->setNextNumber($val+1);
```

Comment: Did you check what data type have returns this line  $list[0]->getNextNumber() with using var_dumb(), then you can recognise how handle that value.

Comment: var_dump($list[0]->getNextNumber()) returns null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $val = (float)$list[0]->getNextNumber();
    $list[0]->setNextNumber($val+1);
```

Comment: (float)$list[0]->getNextNumber() returns 4.6000047220575E+15
(float)$list[0]->getNextNumber()+1 also returns 4.6000047220575E+15

So +1 never increments it further

Answer (score 0):

since PHP treat number as number, it won't be a problem, but if you want to display its value somewhere, cast it to string

```
$val = $list[0]->getNextNumber()+1;
$val = (string)$val
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
$val =$list[0]->getNextNumber();
$val=++$val;
$list[0]->setNextNumber($val);
```

If it not works, show your full code (might be a problem in function code).